# cant select dynamic div and use only its image

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a simple question regarding jquery, i have a long list of images directly uploaded from youtube, the image have the same `v-code` as the video itself, so for simpe downloading of all the videos on one page for browsers i made a list of images, once u click it, the video will appear on its place, the thing is that the code that i have oriented for video's image, but not on another one, anyway here is the code:

```
$('.youtube_thumb > img').click(function(){
    var parts = this.src.split("/");
    var id = parts[parts.length-2];
    $('<iframe width="50%" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').insertAfter(this);
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".name,.detail,.youtube_play").hide();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

and the div

```
<div class="youtube">
    <div class="name">
            #left(name,30)#
    </div>
    <div class="detail">#left(detail,50)#</div>
    <div class="youtube_play"></div>
    <div class="youtube_thumb">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/#link#/0.jpg" style="width:50%;height:300px;border:0;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

as u can see the code takes the img's src and sort the `v-code` and then put it inside the frame. But i want to work this code only after i click on the class `youtube_play` but not on `youtube_thumb`'s image.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.youtube_play').click(function(){
    var img = $(this).next().find('>img');
    var parts = img.get(0).src.split("/");
    var id = parts[parts.length-2];
    $('<iframe width="50%" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').insertAfter(img.get(0));
    img.parent().parent().find(".name,.detail,.youtube_play").hide();
    img.remove();
});
```

Comment: Nope... Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Comment: I've updated code. Btw. you could achieve what you want better and simpler. But that is not the scope of your question :)